# Fedora 24 boot stops at "Starting Switch Root..." after disabling udev/udisks

Tags: fedora, systemd, udev, dracut

I'm installing a new Fedora 24 system, and just for "fun", I ran this command:

`systemctl -t service|grep 'loaded active running'| perl -anle 'print "systemctl stop $F[0]; systemctl disable $F[0]"' | sh`

which attempts to turn off and disable all services.

'auditd' refuses to stop with an error, but all other services stop fine.

I also disabled "systemd-udevd-kernel.socket" and 
"systemd-udevd-control.socket" because the command above warned me 
that these sockets could restart systemd-udevd.

After `shutdown -r`, the boot process gets as far as "Starting Switch 
Root..." and hangs. In particular:

- The cursor below this message starts blinking at a normal rate, 
  but then turns to flickering extremely rapidly.
- Normally, when I screw things up like this, I get a dracut timeout 
  with a minimal shell that lets me fix things. This time, no dracut 
  timeout.

I strongly suspect that disabling "system-udevd" was a seriously bad 
idea. Is there any way I can fix this without reinstalling?

And, if so, which services should I absolutely avoid disabling?

Comment: Install [etckeeper](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/etckeeper) so that recovering from misconfigurations is just a matter of `git reset --hard`.

Answer (score 2):

> I strongly suspect that disabling "system-udevd" was a seriously bad idea.

Well, your whole proposed enterprise was fraught with possibility of failure.

> Is there any way I can fix this without reinstalling?

I'd try to boot with a LiveCD (even from another distro) and chroot in and re-enable all of the services. But then I wouldn't be in such a mess in the first place.

> which services should I absolutely avoid disabling?

The services in the base install are there for a reason. If you want a sane, working system, don't disable anything (unless you are installing a drop-in replacement for one of them). If you just want to play around and determine the minimum set of services that will get you to a login prompt, you'll have to do the trial and error work yourself.